# Angular2 browser cache

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**Brief description:** I am trying to handle the cache issue for an angular app on browser. I don't want my client to clear cache every time I update it.

So I have followed this [tutorial](https://csjdpw.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/~Genhan.Chen/pages/43393408/Angular+2+browser+cache+cleaning+issue)

**Problem:** In my `home.ts` , I am making my

```
templateUrl: 'home.html',
```

to

```
templateUrl: 'home.html?v=1.0',
```

Then it gives me a 404 error.

What is wrong? I want to give version number to my `home.html` page.

Comment: how is this related to cache ? everytime u generate a dist folder, append some random number in JS. it will make sure that client will not have to clear the cache.

Comment: where shall i append the number, can you elaborate ?

Comment: in ionic there is - `<script src="build/main.js"></script>` in `index.html`, shall i change it to `<script src="build/mainv1.js"></script>`

Comment: When u generate the bundle, u change the name of the file. For example main.11be21115bccde021618.js .. now when i generate the bundle again, it will be different main.randomnumber.js ...........this will ensure that users wont have to reload. Tools like Angular CLI auto generate it

Answer (score 1):

Cache bustin is handled by the CLI.

Simply run your command with

```
ng build --prod
```

And the cache busting will take effect.

You can also set up a custom parameter in your `angular.json` config, but since it changes depending on your Angular version, I'm going to ask you your Angualr version first.

And also, the error is popping because your file is called `home.html`, not `home.html?v=1.0`. You're not handling URLS in your decorators, you're telling the compiler what files to open (and convert to JS).

Comment: i am using ionic, may be this is the reason ?

Comment: I don't know ionic. How do you build your application ?

Comment: npm run ionic: build --prod

Comment: open your `package.json` and tell me what the `ionic:build` command runs

Comment: Okay, then you should refer to ionic documentation about cache busting